# Software for sharing a live webcam stream with audio

Tags: streaming, webcam

My friend is getting married in November and has asked me to look into setting a webcam feed with audio for the ceremony. Does anyone have any suggestions of some software they have used which has provided good results. I would prefer to use a branded product (MS or skype) rather than something randomly downloaded.

If you can configure skype to let multiple people view though a Cam that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, Skype does not support conference video calls right now - it's only 1 to 1.

In fact, using an IM is probably a bad idea, as your bandwidth needs to support streaming the video to ALL cam attendees - with full data streams for each *individual* viewer.

What I suggest you to do is to use a video live streaming service, such as [UStream](http://www.ustream.tv/), and let your invitees know the video stream URL. that way, your bandwidth is secure.

Better still - get an AV team who knows how to get a reliable video feed online. It's a wedding, it's once in a lifetime, and it's not yours.

Comment: Good luck, Kev. Make sure you do a trial run first and test how well the video handles under load!

Answer (score 2):

Skype doesn't support video conferencing, [**ooVoo**](http://www.oovoo.com/) does.

or setup a webcam server so the stream can be viewed in a browser without a client (e.g. [SasCam](http://download.cnet.com/SasCam-Webcam-Server/3000-2348_4-10491197.html))

Comment: setting up a local webcam server - like the one you suggested - will run into bandwidth issues as it needs to support a full data stream to each *individual* viewer.