# Software to stream a home webcam

Tags: home-networking, streaming, webcam

I am visiting my family for a few days and would like to setup a webcam at my apartment to stream video while I am gone.

I found [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/38647/software-for-sharing-a-live-webcam-stream-with-audio), but the answer isn't really what I was looking for.

I more interested in desktop software, such as [WebcamXP](http://www.webcamxp.com/home.aspx), but was wondering if there were any alternatives.

Comment: Do you mean like surveillance, so that you can make sure your house is still in tact while you are gone?

Answer (score 2):

I assume your under Windows?
I think it would be easier under a linux variant.

but for windows try these: http://news.cnet.com/8301-27076_3-10301349-248.html 
one of my buddies is using ugolog

EDIT:
In that case use ubuntu. There are lots of tutorials out there.
http://infectedproject.wordpress.com/2007/06/26/set-up-a-webcam-security-system/
and:
http://www.chriswpage.com/2009/05/setup-an-advanced-webcam-security-system-with-ubuntu-8-04-and-motion/

Comment: Dual boot Windows 7 x64, and Ubuntu 10.10

Answer (score 1):

It isn't the easiest solution, but should also work cross platform.

If you install [VLC Media Player](http://www.videolan.org) on whatever machine you want to be the server, and if the webcam is correctly installed, VLC should be able to pick it up and stream it across a network.

You can then use another copy of VLC (or anything else that supports the protocol) to watch what is being shown.

I would also say to test this before you go from an outside connection just to make sure that all ports and everything are configured correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need recording capabilities, or just the ability to check in on your apartment?  A quick and dirty solution would be to create a ustream.tv account and just stream using that.

Comment: Just need to check in. I may try ustream.tv